# Classic ASP TouchActionButton

Tags: asp-classic

An admin panel we're using uses a SubActionButton which is currently handling all links from the main panel.
I think it's due to the fact the Sub uses a form that it always appears as a button, I want it to appear as a simple text link but I can't figure out how.

```
sub TouchActionButton(Link, LinkName, LinkText)
Response.write "<div style=""float: left;""><form method=""post"" action=""" & Link & """><input type=""submit"" name=""" & LinkName & """ value=""" & LinkText & """ style=""height: 40px;"" ></form></div>"   
end sub
```

This is the Sub in the global config file.

```
TouchActionButton "../Admin/","page","Manage Users"
```

Then this is used to display the button link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to do a submit you must make use of `JavaScript`/ `JQuery` to make a postback using an anchor tag (`<a>`). You can not submit a form using an `<a>` tag alone.

There are few ways of submitting a form using an `<a>` tag. They are,

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">Submit the Form</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form-id').submit()">Submit the Form</a>
```

The safest is to use an id for the `<form>`

So, here's the solution for you.

```
sub TouchActionButton(Link, LinkName, LinkText)
Response.write "<div style='float: left;'><form id='form-id' method='post' action='" & Link & "'><a name='" & LinkName & "' href='#' onclick='JavaScript: document.getElementById(''form-id'').submit()'>" & LinkText & "</a></form></div>"   
end sub
```

Hope this helped! If it did, vote and accept answer :)

Comment: with regard to your first paragraph, that's not entirely true: the user can put the form's link in with an appropriate query string attached (e.g. `href="myform.asp?a=123&b=<%= bValue %>"`), though this is not technically a post, more simply a call to the page with arguments.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. But, the user just needs to keep the same functionality as the button with a link. That's why I suggested this.